# How to Decrypt private key(String) with passphrase - java

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, private-key

I am trying to decrypt the private key in a string. The key also has a passphrase. My Private key file has the following header and footer:

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\n
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

I could see more `'\n'` new line inside the private key. I hope it's in pem format.

The last line of the following code gives me this error:

> PBE parameter parsing error: expecting the object identifier for AES
>   cipher

This is the code I tried:

```
String privateKeyPEM = a;
privateKeyPEM = privateKeyPEM.replace("-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "");
privateKeyPEM = privateKeyPEM.replace("-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "");
byte[] encoded = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(privateKeyPEM);
EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo pkinfo = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(encoded);
```

I have also tried using **bouncy castle** but I am getting the following error

> class "org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPublicKey"'s signer information
>   does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Note: I'm using jdk11

I would appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question to determine why you're having a problem. When I use your code with a known valid private key in the same format I get no errors.

Comment: (1) Yes PEM format does have (required) line breaks in the base64 'blob'; see wikipedia and/or rfc7468 section 2. (2) Confirm if you are using `javax/crypto/EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo` and not any of several other classes with the same relative name. If so the ctor should never give such an error, but an added or subsequent `getKeySpec(various)` might do so depending the data in the keyfile. If you have openssl, look at `openssl asn1parse -i -in pemfile` (or `-in derfile -inform der`), or add to your Q (by editting) with the last OCTET STRING redacted (that's your actual encrypted key data)

Comment: (3) your bouncycastle problem is a different problem; if you want to pursue it, ask a separate question and describe exactly what jar you are using. In particular if you put bcprov into any repackaging such as 'one-jar' 'single-jar' maven gradle Ecliipse Intellij Netbeans etc that won't work.

Comment: If you can supply the sample encrypted message with a key (otherwise known as a [mcve]), then someone might be able to debug it further.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your private key is encrypted with AES ciphers.

At the beginning of your encrypted private key file, you can see something like below:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-CBC,2241040B6A6E0FBE
```

The `DEK-Info` tells you what encryption algorithm is in use.

You can use `openssl` to convert the cipher:

```
openssl rsa -in des.pem -aes256 -out aes.pem
```

to get an AES encrypted private key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,40FACC69B7E9ED576BF8300B871701EB
```

As of today, `javax.crypto` still only supports AES ciphers only per [JDK-8076999](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8076999). And that's why you would get this error:

```
PBE parameter parsing error: expecting the object identifier for AES cipher
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public PrivateKey readPrivateKey(String privateKeyContent,String passPhrase) {
  PrivateKey privateKey = null;
  try {
    PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(new StringReader(privateKeyContent));
    byte[] content = pemReader.readPemObject().getContent();
    EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encryptPKInfo = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(content);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptPKInfo.getAlgName());
    PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray());
    SecretKeyFactory secFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(encryptPKInfo.getAlgName());
    Key pbeKey = secFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
    AlgorithmParameters algParams = encryptPKInfo.getAlgParameters();
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, algParams);
    KeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = encryptPKInfo.getKeySpec(cipher);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }
  return privateKey;
}
```