# I have RSA encrypted private key with passphrase how do I decrypt the private key file

Tags: java, bouncycastle, java-security

Basically I want to do this in command in java

```bash
openssl rsa -in enc_private.key -out private.key -passin pass:passphrase_xyz
```

beginning of my encrypted key file looks like this

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,59e5e15b3d9474e6
```

please assist.

Comment: Seems like this isn't possible for now https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020403/20443541

Comment: Maybe https://commandlinefanatic.com/cgi-bin/showarticle.cgi?article=art050 helps you

Comment: I couldn't find any solution for it either, for now I have added script which is called from dockerfile to execute these steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("openssl rsa -in enc_private.key -out private.key -passin pass:passphrase_xyz");
```

Maybe a bash or PowerShell script would be better suited?

Comment: I ran this command form docker file but suggestion was to make it part of application once it is started so I guess will settle for above suggested approach. I was trying to understand if there is a way to achieve this using java libraries.